# Delete row data from Firebase

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angularfire2, smart-table

I want to delete one clicked row from Firebase in my smart table. I am using Angular 4.

The smart table code:

```
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="bicycleData"
 (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)">
</ng2-smart-table>
```

My constructor component code:

```
constructor(
    db: AngularFireDatabase, ) {
    this.bicyclesList = db.list('bicycle-list')
        .snapshotChanges()
        .map(changes => {
            return changes.map(c => ({
                    key: c.payload.key,
                    ...c.payload.val()
                }))
        });

    this.bicyclesList.subscribe((data) => {
        this.bicycleData = data;
    });
}
```

and component.ts code:

```
settings = {
    delete : {
        deleteButtonContent: '<i class="nb-trash"></i>',
        confirmDelete: true,
    },
}
```

onDeleteConfirm() function and deleteEnquiry function in service:

```
onDeleteConfirm(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
        this.deleteEnquiry(event.data);
        event.confirm.resolve();
    } else {
        event.confirm.reject();
    }
}

deleteEnquiry(data) {
    console.log(data.$key);
    this.db.list(`bicycle-list${data.$key}`).remove(data);
}
```

But it keeps showing me the following error in console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined
```

How can I fix this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an error in `deleteEnquiry`.

According to the [docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md) is should be:

```
deleteEnquiry(data) {
  console.log(data.$key);
  this.db.list('bicycle-list').remove(data.$key);
}
```